# If the intersection of an open set with a closed set is non-empty....

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Let $(X, \tau)$ be any topological space. Let ${O}$ be any open set, and let $V$ be any other set (not necessarily open or closed). Suppose that

$O \cap closure(V) \not= \emptyset$.

Is it true that

$O \cap V \not= \emptyset$

as well? Here is my proof attempt:

Let $x \in O \cap closure(V)$. Then $x \in closure(V)$ implies the existence of some net $(x_{\alpha})_{\alpha \in A}$ of elements of $V$ such that $x_{\alpha} \rightarrow x \in O$. Thus, for some $\hat{\alpha}$, we have $\beta \succeq \hat{\alpha}$ implies $x_{\beta} \in O$. Since such $x_{\beta}$ are elements of $V$, we have $x_{\beta} \in O \cap V \not= \emptyset$.

What do you think? Nobel prize? Thanks!

Comment: In other words, either $O$ contains a point of $V$ or $O$ contains a limit point of $V$. But if $O$ is open and contains a limit point of $V$ then $O$ contains a point of $V$. So $O$ and $V$ have a non-empty intersection if $O$ and the closure of $V$ have a non-empty intersection.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the fact we need "if $x\in cl(A)$ then $U\cap A\neq \emptyset$ for every neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ " And the other side of the fact also true.

Take any $x\in O \cap cl(V)$. Then $x\in O$  and $x\in cl(V)$. By using the fact we get $O \cap V \not= \emptyset$

Comment: Thanks! This looks quicker, but does my proof with nets still go through?

Comment: @Mark Yes you are fine

Comment: @Mark they're not really needed. I'm a fan of nets, but lose them here IMO, the direct definition of a closure point is nicer.